# simpleJWT and dj-rest-auth Cookie based authorization

Tags: django-rest-framework, axios, httpcookie, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, dj-rest-auth

Between dj-rest-auth and simpleJWT I have been able to send the set-cookie messages, store the cookies in the browser, and send them back with each request (Axios' with credentials = true), but it seems like the back-end, no matter what I do, it is always expecting the Authentication Bearer Token.

I see on the github code, that the `rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication` authentication class is only checking for the **Authentication: Bearer Token header**, but there is no way to do it directly with the cookies (no authentication header).

In fact, by default, it seems like Www-Authenticate is bearer dependent, and when using the *dj-rest-framework JWTCookieAuthentication class* is not overriding the authentication method.

Does anyone know how should the setting.py file should be configured to do so out-of-the-box, or is it mandatory to overwrite the authentication classes or create a custom one?

Thanks!

This is my dj-rest-auth cofig and simpleJWT in my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'] = [
        # 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
    ]

REST_AUTH = {
    'USE_JWT': True,
    'JWT_AUTH_SECURE': True,
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'my-auth',
    'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE': 'my-refresh-token',
    'JWT_AUTH_HTTPONLY': True,
    'JWT_AUTH_SAMESITE': 'None',
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

It seems like in dj-rest-auth's jwt_auth library the cookie class has not been updated for the new cookies setup declaration introduced since v.3.

Since version 3, there is a new configuration in the settings using the REST_AUTH dictionary.
Nevertheless, dj-rest-auth/dj_rest_auth/jwt_auth.py is still checking the cookies from v2:

```
...
def authenticate(self, request):
        cookie_name = api_settings.JWT_AUTH_COOKIE
...
```

As it is now located in the dictionary, I extended the class like this, and it worked:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework.authentication import CSRFCheck
from rest_framework import exceptions, serializers
from dj_rest_auth import jwt_auth
from django.conf import settings

class CustomCookieAuthentication(jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        cookie_name = settings.REST_AUTH['JWT_AUTH_COOKIE']
...
```

I opened an issue to see if a PR would be needed: https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/584

I hope it helps other people.